# Unity 2019.3 Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to build my Unity project, which I work on with another developer via the collab system. They don't have any issues and we are on the exact same project version, however, I get this error every time I open the project and haven't been able to find a fix. I have tried reinstalling Unity and messing with the JDK/SDK options a bit, but haven't been able to make any difference.

I am pretty sure it is a problem with the Google Play Services plugin though, and I'm not sure if I've managed to delete some dependencies via Firebase.

Here's the error:`Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found.
  at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExtractZip (System.String zipFile, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] extractFilenames, System.String outputDirectory, System.Boolean update) [0x00132] in Z:\tmp\tmp.ab7x7pd8vv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PlayServicesResolver\src\PlayServicesResolver.cs:2437 
  at Google.GradleWrapper.Extract (Google.Logger logger) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.ab7x7pd8vv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PlayServicesResolver\src\GradleWrapper.cs:100 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.GradleResolution (System.String destinationDirectory, System.String androidSdkPath, System.Boolean logErrorOnMissingArtifacts, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action`1[T] resolutionComplete) [0x00093] in Z:\tmp\tmp.ab7x7pd8vv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PlayServicesResolver\src\GradleResolver.cs:267 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver.DoResolutionUnsafe (System.String destinationDirectory, System.Boolean closeWindowOnCompletion, System.Action resolutionComplete) [0x000bc] in Z:\tmp\tmp.ab7x7pd8vv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PlayServicesResolver\src\GradleResolver.cs:820 
  at GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver+<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.ab7x7pd8vv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\PlayServicesResolver\src\GradleResolver.cs:710 
  at Google.RunOnMainThread.ExecuteNext () [0x0003d] in Z:\tmp\tmp.c5cHAkrYVv\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\VersionHandlerImpl\src\RunOnMainThread.cs:377 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:379)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:363)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:DoResolution(String, Boolean, Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:709)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1786)
GooglePlayServices.c__AnonStorey5:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1604)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1461)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ScheduleResolve(Boolean, Boolean, Action`1, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1617)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1134)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:<ScheduleAutoResolve>m__8() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.ab7x7pd8vv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1113)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:300)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:414)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.c5cHAkrYVv/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()`

Also, I don't have a Z drive on my device.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just like Anton R said above, I also did the following!

This is how i fixed it:

Open Preferences/External Tools/

Then uncheck and check again all check marks under "Android"

Android resolver will start after entering playmode and automatically resolve all issues.

But it followed up with a win32exception error, gradlewbawt file not found.
To fix it, open this link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/master/gradlew.bat

and download the gradlew.bat file then place it in your :
C:\Users\STEPHEN\Game1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\ path. This is mine, yours will be different.
Make sure you save the file as gradlew.bat.

Answer (score 2):

After spending ages trying to fix this and then decided to post this request, I managed to fix it.

Not 100% sure how I did it, but when I switched to a different scene and tried to enter play mode, "Android Dependency Resolver" opened and scanned for issues, found some and then fixed them.

Hope that's enough to help anyone who gets a similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it:

Open Preferences/External Tools/

Then uncheck and check again all check marks under "Android"

Android resolver will start after entering playmode and automatically resolve all issues.