Unity unable to find Android JDK in the system path
I'm trying to install LevelPlay (IronSource) and the Android resolver fails saying that the path to the JDK is incorrect.
I've spent 2 days on this, trying everything and It's driving me NUTS.
I've followed every single solutions found on sourceforge.
Especially the most common:

Go to Unity Preferences -> External tools and check/uncheck everything
under android.

I've check the paths are correct.
I've even uninstalled and reinstalled unity with the hub.
It keeps saying it can't find the JDK.
Job failed with exception:

GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found.
at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExtractZip (System.String
zipFile,

I'm on my last leg. Can anybody help please?

Job failed with exception: GooglePlayServices.JavaUtilities+ToolNotFoundException: jar not found.
at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.ExtractZip (System.String zipFile,

jar is not jdk.

I know... The issue is related to an issue with the Java JDK that unity can't find for some reason

Can you clarify on the issue? Can you add the detailed error messages and the preferences window?

It's exactly the same poblem than here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028829/unity-2019-3-job-failed-with-exception-googleplayservices-javautilitiestoolnot    But all the solutions provided don't work
